# Отдельные модели под пользователей и администраторов

Tags: python, django

Ребята, помогите.

Стоит задачка собрать джанго проект -

Админка

- Нужна стандартная админка Django (пользователи админки могут не
  пересекаться с пользователями в таблице Users)**

Не могу понять пункт с Админкой, как создать вторую модель с юзерами и что бы там отображались только юзеры без прав администратора. А в другой модели отображались только администраторы.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Это отрывок из целого тестового задания для трудоустройства в компанию для джуна. Другую часть задания всю выполнил, а эту часть вообще не понимаю как сделать. Либо эта задача не совсем подходит для джуна....

Comment: @RomanKonoval поменял в шапке описание задания, что думаете на этот счет? как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что задание подразумевает, что вы можете создать свою модель `User`, и не использовать стандартную из `django.contrib.auth`.

И вообще не использовать стандартную аутентификацию, а реализовать свою для своих view. В этом случае можно использовать стандартный механизм аутентификации в django admin (именно это означает приписка, что пользователи "могут не пересекаться", т.е. ваша таблица пользователей для тех view, что вы реализовали, а django пользователи только для админки).

Вам будет достаточно подключить django admin приложение [стандартным способом](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/) и создать пользователя django командой [createsuperuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-createsuperuser). То есть вам не нужно реализовывать вторую модель пользователя, а использовать готовую из джанго (собственно она и так используется по умолчанию, даже если вы об этом не подозреваете).

И еще, задание не заставляет вас создавать вторую модель. Оно *разрешает* вам использовать две независимые модели. Одну для самого сайта (это вы напишете сами), вторую - для админки (тут не нужно писать, нужно только сконфигурировать приложение django admin).

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение.
Интересно, а для кастомной модели пользователей нужно ли давать возможность работать через JWT токены для просмотра статей после авторизации.

Comment: Из задания следует, что это вам решать. Хотите ли вы использовать JWT (а это значит, что имя пользователя и пароль зашиты в сам токен и вам нет нужды его хранить в БД, а значит и модель `Token` не нужна) или использовать другой вид токенов (по сути случайный набор символов, в этом случае нужно знать к какому пользователю вы привязали этот токен, и тогда такой токен нужно хранить в БД). Т.е. задание говорит, что нужно использовать токены. А какой вид - это вы сами решайте.